# How would one say «run something past somebody» in Russian

Tags: перевод, phrase

For example, i can say: «Can i run this idea past you?» meaning that i want to get feedback from a person or «I ran this past the director, and he agrees.» meaning that the plan was approved by the director.

The person, who the idea or a plan is being ran past, рецензирует this idea. But what is the verb for presenting for such input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю здесь могут подойти слова показать/посмотреть:

> Можешь посмотреть мое предложение?
>
> Я показал свое предложение директору и он согласился (не возражал).

Есть и более официальное слово - рассмотреть:

> Директор рассмотрит ваше предложение в понедельник.
>
> Я представил свой проект на рассмотрение.

Comment: I suppose the answer probably was much simpler than i thought it was…

Answer (score 2):

Much more idiomatic would be: "хочу с тобой посоветоваться по вопросу..." or "нужен твой совет насчет..."

Answer (score 2):

In addition to посмотреть and рассмотреть I'd like to mention an informal, idiomatic, but still commonly used провентилировать (lit. to ventilate as in freshen the air).

> Я бы тут хотел с тобой одну идейку провентилировать...

Wouldn't go with a director though.